# how to align my "remember me" check box to the center?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I tried to align my checkbox and label to the center of the screen but it wasn't moving at all. i tried to put it in the container tag but it result in the label of the check box is not align together.  can someone please help with this problem?

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  clear: both;
}

.container input {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv= "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE=edge">
    <meta name= "viewport" content = "width=device-width,initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<form action="<?= $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" class="p-4">
<div class= "form-group"></div>
<input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Phone" required>

<div class= "form-group"></div>
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" required>
</div>

<form>  
<label>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
Remember me 
</label>
</form>






<div class="container">     
<p>
<div class="form-group">
<input type ="submit" name="login"
class="btn btn-block" >
</p>
</div>

</body>



    



            
</html>
```

Comment: Html closing tags are missing, code totally messy !. required edit and formatting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  clear: both;
}

.container input {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
/* add this style */
label {
  display: flex !important; 
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" class="p-4">
      <div class="form-group"></div>
      <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Phone" required>

      <div class="form-group"></div>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" required>
  </div>

  <form>
    <label>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
Remember me 
</label>
  </form>






  <div class="container">
    <p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-block">
    </p>
    </div>

</body>








</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your label in HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv= "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE=edge">
    <meta name= "viewport" content = "width=device-width,initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<form action="<?= $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" class="p-4">
<div class= "form-group"></div>
<input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Phone" required>

<div class= "form-group"></div>
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" required>
</div>

<form>  
<label class = "checkbox">
<input  type="checkbox" checked>
Remember me 
</label>
</form>

<div class="container">     
<p>
<div class="form-group">
<input type ="submit" name="login"
class="btn btn-block" >
</p>
</div>

</body>

            
</html>
```

And then in your CSS move it to the right:

```
   .container {
  width: 350px;
  clear: both;
}

.container input {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.checkbox {
  left: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

- Make a div tag center contain the label checkbox.
- Set label fullwidth and text center